# Rolling average in redshift based on varying dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have some data that looks like the following:

```
2017-06-19  121344.4
2017-06-19  1603435
2017-06-16  53341.3
2017-06-16  980
2017-06-12  2391.8
2017-06-12  1874
2017-05-17  103420.8
2017-05-17  1201
2017-05-16  5075.6
2017-05-16  46341
2017-05-10  1925.4
2017-05-10  170343
2017-04-19  864343.8
2017-04-19  1053245
2017-04-18  434
```

As you can see the frequency of the dates varies and is not consistently on a distinct date. I also have a date dimension table that lists every day for all the relevant months that I join on year and date. I would like to produce a query that averages by day for all days of the month. Is this possible? My desired results would be Date, avg(value) over days

Comment: "I would like to produce a query that averages the values by day based on the interval between the last previous date."  I don't get it.  Perhaps editing the question and adding in your desired results would help.

Comment: ok made some changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic consists of the following steps:
1) get count and sum of the variable for every day
2) left join to the calendar that you mentioned
3) calculate average as sum/count in the desired rolling window (this way you will avoid averaging the average which is mathematically incorrect)

```
with 
daily_summaries as (
    select
     date
    ,count(1)
    ,sum(var)
    from table
    group by 1
)
,summaries_to_calendar as (
    select
     c.month
    ,c.date
    ,s.count as daily_count
    ,s.sum as daily_sum
    from calendar c
    left join daily_summaries s
    on c.date=s.date
)
select
 *
,coalesce(round(1.0*
    sum(daily_sum) over (partition by month order by date rows between  unbounded preceding and current row) /
    sum(daily_count) over (partition by month order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
 ,2),0) as monthly_rolling_avg
from summaries_to_calendar;
```

This will calculate averages for every day looking back until 1st day of the month. If your dataset would be only the sample in the question, the output row for 2017-06-11 will be 0, for 2017-06-12 it will be the average for all entries of 2017-06-12, for 2017-06-16 it will be the average of all entries for 2017-06-12 AND 2017-06-16 and so on. You can choose different window if you want but the principle is the same.

Comment: For the daily_summaries shouldnt there be a group by clause?

Comment: @user3609179 sure!

Comment: I would also like to show all the calander dates of the current month so it can be a complete time series how would I do that?

Comment: you said you have the table with dates, it's used in the query above and shows all dates. if you want just the current month then filter it with `where date_trunc('month',date)=date_trunc('month',current_date)` where `date` is your date column

Comment: Yes so I would like the result to have all dates of the month. With the averages by day for the numeric column. If that makes sense?

Comment: @user3609179 "I would like the result to have all dates of the month" do you mean that you'd like to see a row for every day or you mean that every day's average should include values from all previous days of the same month?

Comment: @user3609179 I asked about two options which is not yes/no question. If you'd like to see the latter this is what the query above does, have you checked it?

Comment: sorry I would like to see a row for every day.

Comment: @user3609179 have you ran the query? there should be a row for every day (assuming `calendar` table has all dates in sequence like calendar)

Comment: hmmm I think I might have confused some column names because when I run the query it only shows the months and not all the dates

Comment: @user3609179 in `summaries_to_calendar` subquery I have included both `month` and `date`, and next query is `select * ...` so you should see both

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average per day, you would do:

```
select day, avg(value)
from t
group by day;
```

If you also wanted the cumulative average, assuming one value per day with data:

```
select day, avg(value),
       avg(avg(value)) over (order by day range between unbounded preceding and current row)
from t
group by day;
```

Perhaps one of these is what you are looking for.

Comment: Does that work and divide the values by the number of days in the interval?

Comment: @user3609179 . . . Yes, it does.

Comment: I get the following error ERROR:  Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: @user3609179 . . . The strangest absurdity in RedShift.  Why doesn't it just default the window frame, as does every other database?